# how to receive only 1 single value form python to arduino

Tags: python, arduino

I'm new to this!!

python code

```
i = results[1]
i *= 100
if i >= 75:
    print('Recognised as owner!')
    arduino.write(str.encode('1'))
else:
    print('not matches')
```

serial monitor

```
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111...
```

Arduino code

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo;

char value1;
void setup()
{
  servo.attach(8);
  servo.write(0);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0)

  value1 = Serial.read();
  Serial.print(value1);

if (value1 == '1') {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  servo.write(90);
  delay(100);
  }  
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--){
      Serial.println("go inside!!, hurry up !!");
      delay(1000);
    }
  servo.write(0);
  Serial.println("door is closed");
  delay(1000); 
}
```

question:

1. this program can handle the door system based on face recognition
2. the Arduino takes the value of "1" over and over. so later servo always looping every 10 s. because the program cant handles 1 single value.
3. my goal is to make sure that the Arduino only get 1 single input. so later the servo is running well

ty

Comment: (1) The Python code is invalid because of bad indentation. (2) What is "rat"?

Comment: what is rat? if you only want to send a single byte, why do you write in a loop?

Comment: even if i delete that loop at the python code. still the arduino receive 11111111111

Comment: i just want to get a single "1" . any suggestion ?